# Delta Faucet leaks from the bottom

Tags: faucet, delta

I am having my Delta kitchen faucet leak from the very bottom (image attached, marked red). I checked, it's not the hose connection itself, but from the faucet body itself, above the sink. Any ide how could I stop it?

Also adding a picture about the faucet itself, if anyone knows how can I remove the middle part (spout), please let me know, since I want to check the O-rings.

[image]
[image]